# phpMyAdmin, while import csv the text is cut off

Tags: php, mysql, database, csv, phpmyadmin

I import a csv file into myphpamdin.
I have a column conatining text. The import is going fine and everything is getting updated beside the text which get cut off in the middle.

Table example:

"first_name"   "last_name"   "person_details"

"John"      "Smith"      "some long text that getting cut in the middle"

I tried to set the "person_details" to LONGTEXT but the "some long text" still getting cut in the middle.

Comment: I think we need a bit more information.
Could you provide the schema, at least for the field in question?

Comment: Thanks for the comment,  
I have a csv file with row containing person name, person last name and person details. The person details has, lets say 200 words. When I import the csv to the myphpadmin database the database cut the text off. I tried to set the person details column in the database from text to longtext but it still act the same. any other idea?

Comment: Do you have any last names with like O'Callahan or the like?  You maybe running into issue with last names like that where you need to double: ' with a '' ..  Just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some long text must have \n, \r, \t between it echo the long text and see it its source ode and you will find the cause

(in firefox righht click-> view page source) do not use firebug or something similar they are the smart tools they interpret these characters according to them

Comment: Thanks Arpita. The mysql cut the text where there is ' inside the string. Do you know how can I configure the myphpadmin to import the csv correctly?

Comment: I set the myphpadmin - Columns escaped with: \' but it returns an error. where should I set the \'?

Comment: I guess I was not able to explain my thing, I wanted to say add \' where you are creating the CSV.

Comment: Working! Thanks a lot Arpita :)